# User 'reputation system' - Checking if a user has already +1 -1'd someone?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User_Rep` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `REPPER_USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `REP` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

This is my current table, please ignore the missing foreign key for the user_id's, just not added them for brevity.

When a user decides to rep someone, a new record is added to this table, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO `User_Rep` (`ID`, `USER_ID`, `REPPER_USER_ID`, `REP`) VALUES
(1, 72, 3, 1),
(2, 72, 3, 1),
(3, 72, 3, -1);
```

And i can pull any particular users rep with the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(REP) FROM User_Rep WHERE USER_ID = 72
```

However, i'm struggling to devise the appropriate query to use to ascertain whether a particular user has already upvoted or downvoted a user, such that the UI can respond accordingly and perform the relevant action (up vote or down vote)

What happens when a user upvotes, downvotes, upvotes again, etc... and there is now multiple of those rows in the table? How could i find only the relevant True/False?

Any assistance with this?

Comment: In this simple case a unique index on (user_id, repper_user_id) would do. But if it were just like here at SO then you should add another column as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is to change your table.  I would delete the existing ID column and create a UNIQUE index on the USER_ID and REPPER_USER_ID fields.  This will prevent the database from allowing duplicates in the first place, and will also vastly speed up the next part.

Then in code so you can prevent the vote function/button from being available:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `User_Rep` WHERE `USER_ID`=72 AND `REPPER_USER_ID`=3
```

To get the actual vote from 3 to 72, it would be:

```
SELECT `REP` FROM `User_Rep` WHERE `USER_ID`=72 AND `REPPER_USER_ID`=3
```

But be careful how you use that in code... if you do a simple "if true" test you might get -1 or 0, and then any true/false evaluation would return FALSE, even though it's set (zero and negative usually translates to "false".

Assign that to a property/variable in code, then you can then do your check in code to check for evaluation.  Depends what you're using:

Python:

```
if has_voted:
    ...
```

PHP

```
if(has_voted==TRUE) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How will i know if that vote they made is a +1 or a -1? e.g. If the user has upvoted the person, downvote them instead, (one vote per user)

Comment: That's a completely different question.  I've posted the solution to checking if user 3 has already (up|down)voted user 72.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: hd1, why not remove the ID? It's redundant if the user has already voted? (unless you're allowed multiple votes, in which case there's little point in having an up/down vote... you might as well just have a single vote with an incrementing/decrementing value.

Comment: xBroak: should people be allowed to vote twice on the same person?

Comment: They can only up-vote once, if for instance they tap the hypothetical button again, it would down-vote instead, essentially removing their 'vote'

Comment: Okay, please read the answer again from the start.  I've made some changes.  Somebody edited it and removed the bit about removing the ID, but I believe it's redundant in this case.

Comment: and insert into the table with overwrite on conflict?

Comment: Sure, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... :)